# Seagate HDD writing speed too slow?

Tags: usb, external-hdd

I just purchased a seagate 2 TB new HDD. At first it gave me writing speed of around 60MBPS but now its giving me speed of around 7.0MBPS.

I ran and found theis result.

```
friday@friday:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
friday@friday:~$
```

Should I return the HDD to amazon or its just normal or Its functioning on 2.0 ports , (I have plugged it in my 3.0) and using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: What's the file system format on the disk?

Comment: The drive came with NTFS file format and I haven't formatted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seagate HDDs give lesser read write latency when you use them for the first time.

After a while, when the HDD fills up more then 50%, Seagate will perform its reputed 3.0 speed ie. around 100MBPS write and 150MBPS read speed.